# Is there a way to stop per character updates in Ractive?

Tags: ractivejs

I would like to prevent Ractive from updating the DOM until after an iput field blur event. By default Ractive updates the DOM any time a character in typed into or removed from a field. Changing the field in question results in a metered API call, so reducing the number of calls is critical. I know I could display a field that is not part of the Ractive config.data, but that brinings in other issues.

Is this possible? I can't find anything in the Ractive docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be controlled via the `lazy` option, docs are [here](https://ractive.js.org/api/#lazy_1), which limits to change and blur events:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    template: '<input value="{{foo}}">',
    data: { foo: 'bar' },
    lazy: true
});

// will not fire as user is typing
ractive.on('change', function(){
      // only happens on exiting <input> or return if submit
      console.log('changed!')
})
```

The `lazy` option can also be [specified per element](https://ractive.js.org/api/#lazy), not just at the component level.

```
<input value="{{foo}}" lazy="true" />
```

You can also specify a debouncing timeout treshhold:

```
<input value="{{foo}}" lazy="1000" />
```

Comment: @user2799279 Please, don't forget to set this answer as accepted if it solves your question.